# xmlrpc function in another file

Tags: hooks

I would like to put all my xmlrpc functions in a separate inc file and the problem is, how would we tell drupal it is in another file.  Right now, my hook_xmlrpc in my module file looks like this:

```
function mymodule_xmlrpc() {

  $methods['mymodule.get_myfunction'] = 'xmls_mymodule_get_myfunction';
  return $methods;
}
```

xmls_mymodule_get_myfunction resides in mymodule.xml-rpc.inc file.  How do we let drupal know that in this hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `xmls_mymodule_get_myfunction()` as a proxy to the file where the real code is held?

```
function xmls_mymodule_get_myfunction($args) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'MYMODULE', 'MYMODULE.xml-rpc');
  _xmls_mymodule_get_myfunction($args);
}
```

You only incur 4 extra lines of code at the most, and you get the separation you're looking for. Obviously you can extend that function to become generic for several xmlrpc methods, the above is just a very simple example.

Comment: Yeah, I think this might be the best workaround.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can.

Many core hooks, such as [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), let's you define a `file` and a `file path` which Drupal can use to find the actual callbacks for the menu.

However, I don't believe this functionality is supported by [hook_xmlrpc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_xmlrpc/7).

Considering also that the module is likely to [leave core](https://drupal.org/node/1285726) soon, it's unlikely that there will be any large improvements to it.